# Showing junk data in RS485 Protocol using pic24f?

Tags: pic, rs485

I  am working on Rs485 protocol using PIC24f microcontroller and sp3485c as rs485 transceiver ic . I have kept one pic as master and another pic as slave .
when i am transmitting any data from master my slave is not receiving any data it shows junk data by (testing in debugger pickit3). Please suggest me how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Does it work when you just connect the Tx and Rx pins of the micros directly, leaving out the RS 485 driver chips?

Comment: ya by connecting tx and rx pins directly it is receiving data...

Comment: Do you keep the RE' and DE high on one chip, and low on the other, without changing them? These chips might take a while to turn the bus around, so you can't just change it for the length of one byte. Also, are you using a reasonable data rate?

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common method of interconnecting RS485 devices: -

[image]

Note two important things: -

- 0V is common to all slaves and master
- End-of-wire termination resistors (LT) are used

Here's another example: -

[image]

And another here that tries to avoid earth fault currents in an installation: -

[image]

This one is quite pretty too: -

[image]

Note that the black circles around the red and green pair imply a screened cable that is earthed.